# jQuery - onClick add Class to max of 3 elements

Tags: jquery

I have list of items.

OnClick of any item I am toggling `active` class to the item. If it has **3** active elements, I am showing error div. Till here it is working fine.

What I want is:

After reaching `active` classes to **3**, I want to disable this functionality ot other elements. I will be allowed to do that only if I unclick any `active` element (same as error div).

> **[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/as80vb85/1/)**

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var limit = 3;
  $("ul li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    if($("ul li a.active").length >= limit) {
      $("#message").slideDown();
    }else{
     $("#message").slideUp();
    }
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="message">You have reached maximum</div>

  <div id="box1" class="box-containter">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="box2" class="box-containter">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="box3" class="box-containter">
    <h3>Box 3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code below and [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/as80vb85/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var limit = 3;
  $("ul li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($("ul li a.active").length >= limit) {
      $("#message").slideDown();
      if($(this).hasClass("active"))
      {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
       $("#message").slideUp();
      }

    }else{
     $("#message").slideUp();
     $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
  });

});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/as80vb85/2/)

Answer (score 4):

try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var limit = 3;
  $("ul li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  
    if($("ul li a.active").length<limit){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }else{
     $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    if($("ul li a.active").length >= limit) {
      $("#message").slideDown();
    }else{
     $("#message").slideUp();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another variant. you should just a bit change your code in place *toggle* `active`.

1. toggle to *false* always if `message` is visible
2. invert class otherwise

Like this

```
$(this).toggleClass("active",
    !$("#message").is(':visible') && // if message visible always false
    !$(this).hasClass('active')); //toggle active class
```

Sample

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var limit = 3;
  $("ul li").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("active",!$("#message").is(':visible') && !$(this).hasClass('active'));
    if($("ul li a.active").length >= limit) {
      $("#message").slideDown();
    }else{
     $("#message").slideUp();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body{font-family:verdana;font-size:13px;}
.container{width:600px;margin:auto;}
a{color:#000;}
a.active{color:red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;}
.box-containter{float:left;width:30%;margin:0;padding:0;}
ul li{margin:5px;}
#message{display:none;background:#ccc;text-align:center;padding:5px;color:red;margin:50px;border:1px solid #222;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div id="message">You have reached maximum</div>
  
  <div id="box1" class="box-containter">
    <h3>Box 1</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box2" class="box-containter">
    <h3>Box 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="box3" class="box-containter">
    <h3>Box 3</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```